# Disable Hibernate validation for Merge/Update

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I have a POJO called `Order` as follows:

```
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    protected int id;

    @NotNull
    @Future
    protected Date desiredProcessingDate;

    protected Date actualProcessingDate;
}
```

As you can see, desiredProcessingDate must be specified and it must be in the future. A user will submit a new order through a form and specify a `desiredProcessingDate`, which is being validated as expected. The order is then persisted to the database via `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(order);`

At a later date a scheduled service will retrieve the order from the database, process it and stamp the `actualProcessingDate` with the current timestamp.

However, when this service calls `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(order);` the validation kicks in again and fails because `desiredProcessingDate` is now in the past.

It seems like what I need to do is to tell the `merge(order)` operation not to validate, but am unsure how to do this.

If this is not possible then it seems like to only way around it is to write a class-level custom validator which only checks that `desiredProcessingDate` is in the future if `actualProcessingDate == null`, which seems overly complex for what seems like a simple requirement. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: When are you using merge(order)? Is it after the order is already in the database?

Comment: The order is persisted when the user creates it, but an automated (Spring Scheduled) service will retrieve it from the database at a later date, process it, set actualProcessingDate and then update the database.

Comment: My answer was changed. You probably already thought of this though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validation behaviour in JPA can be configured using the the properties  `javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-persist`, `javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-update` and `javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-remove`. The values for these properties is a comma separated list of the fully qualified classnames of the validation groups to target for each of the given JPA life cycle event, eg:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-persist" value="javax.validation.groups.Default,com.acme.PrePersist"/>    
<property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-update" value="javax.validation.groups.Default"/>
```

As a solution to your problem is to add the `@Future` constraint to a "PrePersist" group in which case it only gets validated on persist and not on update.

Answer (score -1):

In actuality I would really do this code in a Backing Bean then in the entity itself, I actually would stress that, but it is up to you. This code will be written in the method that persists the Order and of course @Future will be removed completely.

So in the backing bean you would have

```
//psuedocode
void submitButtonHasBeenPressed(entity){

Date dNow = new Date();
//SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy"); if you need this
if(desiredProcessDateTheUserEnteredInTheField > dNow){
entity.setDesiredProcessingDate(desiredProcessDateTheUserEnteredInTheField);
 }
   else{

   System.out.println("ERROR OCCURED IN VALIDATION");
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,"ERROR OCCURED IN VALIDATION");
   //or show an error Spring style

   }
```

This way it will never get validated twice by accident

Comment: You cannot put a constraint on a setter like this. For validating the state of a bean the constraint needs to be applied on a field or getter. There is also executable validation, but this is a feature of Bean Validation 1.1 (Hibernate Validator 5.x). In this case you need a interceptor framework though.