# Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a error when I try to insert a user in the database.

I made i custom annotation which verify if the password match with the confirmation password it works when the field not matches , but when the passowrd matches i have this error :

[image]

This is my code This is my field match @Annotation :

```
package mereuta.marian.tennis01.annotations;


import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Constraint(validatedBy = FieldsValueMatchValidator.class)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface FieldsValueMatch {

    String message() default "Fields values don't match!";

    String field();

    String fieldMatch();

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    @Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @interface List {
        FieldsValueMatch[] value();
    }
}
```

This is the Field Validator :

```
package mereuta.marian.tennis01.annotations;

import mereuta.marian.tennis01.model.Utilisateur;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class FieldsValueMatchValidator implements ConstraintValidator<FieldsValueMatch , Object> {

    private String field;
    private String fieldMatch;


    @Override
    public void initialize(FieldsValueMatch fieldsValueMatch) {
        this.field=fieldsValueMatch.field();
        this.fieldMatch=fieldsValueMatch.fieldMatch();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {


        Object fieldValue = new BeanWrapperImpl(value)
                .getPropertyValue(field);
        Object fieldMatchValue = new BeanWrapperImpl(value)
                .getPropertyValue(fieldMatch);

        if (fieldValue != null) {
            return fieldValue.equals(fieldMatchValue);
        } else {
            return fieldMatchValue == null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Entity :

```
@FieldsValueMatch(field = "password", fieldMatch = "confirmPassword", 
message = "Password do not match!")
@Entity(name = "utilisateurs")
public class Utilisateur {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id_utilisateur")
    private Integer id;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Transient
    @NotNull
    private String confirmPassword;
```

This is the Controller :

```
@PostMapping("/addUtilisateur")
    public String addUtilisateur(@Valid @ModelAttribute("utilisateur") Utilisateur utilisateur, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {


        if (bindingResult.hasErrors() ) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "le mot de passe ne correspond pas");
            return "utilisateur/formRegister";
        }


        utilisateurMetier.creerUtilisateur(utilisateur);

        return "utilisateur/utilisateurAjoute";


    }
```

And finally the View :

```
<div class="container">
        <form id="contact" th:action="@{addUtilisateur}" method="post" th:object="${utilisateur}">
            <h3>Créer compte</h3>


                <input placeholder="password" type="password" th:field="*{password}" tabindex="2" required/>
                <span class="text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errors="*{password}"></span>

            </fieldset>


            <fieldset>

                <input placeholder="password" type="password" th:field="*{confirmPassword}" tabindex="2" required/>
                <span class="text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('confirmPassword')}"
                      th:errors="*{confirmPassword}" th:text="${message}"></span>


            </fieldset>
```

For the custom annotations I find a example on : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator

```
@Override
    public void creerUtilisateur(Utilisateur utilisateur) {

        Role role;
        float credit = 0;
        boolean actif = true;

        role = roleRepository.getOne(3);


        System.out.println(role);

        BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();


        utilisateur.setPassword(encoder.encode(utilisateur.getPassword()));

        utilisateur.setRole(role);
        utilisateur.setCredit(credit);
        utilisateur.setActif(actif);


        utilisateurRepository.save(utilisateur);
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: please post code of your class 'utilisateurMetier' or at least it's method 'creerUtilisateur'. if you look at your stacktrace you'll see that the ContraintViolationException is thrown inside the 'creerUtilisateur' method.

Comment: I put it , is the last one

Comment: hope my answer solved your issue?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned the ContraintViolationException is thrown inside the 'creerUtilisateur' method. So the validation of your Utilisateur bean at the time it's passed to your Spring MVC controller method (`addUtilisateur(@Valid @ModelAttribute("utilisateur")...`) works correctly when both fields (password, confirmPassword) have the same value. Later, you encode the password and change the value of your Utilitsateur's 'password' instance variable:

```
utilisateur.setPassword(encoder.encode(utilisateur.getPassword()));
```

Now, 'password' and 'passwordConfirm' are not equal anymore! When persisting this entity in `utilisateurRepository.save(utilisateur);` JPA will again bean-validate your entity before saving it to database (pre-persist). The validation gets automatically executed when JPA/Hibernate triggers a pre-persist, pre-update or pre-remove lifecycle event. And then the ContraintViolationException is thrown!

In your `creerUtilisateur` method simply set the encoded password for both, 'password' and 'passwordConfirm', instance variables and hereby ensure that they still pass your equality check in `FieldsValueMatchValidator.isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context)`:

```
 BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
 final String encodedPassword = encoder.encode(utilisateur.getPassword());
 utilisateur.setPassword(encodedPassword);
 utilisateur.setPasswordConfirm(encodedPassword);
 //...
 utilisateurRepository.save(utilisateur);
```

You could also try to customize JPA's bean validation behaviour:

https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/automatically-validate-entities-with-hibernate-validator/

[Disable Hibernate validation for Merge/Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851889/disable-hibernate-validation-for-merge-update)